# How to align equation more to the left?

Tags: equations, align, tex-core

[image: \I want this]

How I can do the numeration and equation format like shown in the picture above?

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
    \begin{align}
    \begin{array}{l}
    P^{TE}_q = Re\frac{j|E_0|^2}{2\eta}\\
    \times \oiint\limits_S(A^i_qA^{i*}_q\bar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(1)*}_q + A^i_qA^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(4)*}_q\\
    + A^s_qA^{i*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(1)*}_q + A^s_qA^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(4)*}_q)\\
    \cdot \hat{r}ds
    \end{array}\\
    \begin{array}{l}
    P^{TM}_q = Re\frac{j|E_0|^2}{2\eta}\\
    \times \oiint\limits_S(B^i_qB^{i*}_q\bar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(1)*}_q + B^i_qB^{s*}_q\bar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(4)*}_q\\
    + B^s_qB^{i*}_q\bar{N}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(1)*}_q + B^s_qB^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(4)*}_q)\\
    \cdot \hat{r}ds
    \end{array}
    \end{align}
```

but only get this [image]

Comment: Please state which document class you use and what the main font size is.

Comment: please edit that informtaion into your question.  it would be best if you modify the code that is already there to make a compilable example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Observe that I would recommend *not* specifying the option `fleqn`. I recommend using a single `align` environment and no `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article} % no 'fleqn' option
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,esint}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\let\Re\relax 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re} % redefine '\Re'
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of column
\setcounter{equation}{24} % just for this example
\begingroup
\thickmuskip=0mu
\medmuskip=0mu
\thinmuskip=0mu
\small
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
P^{\mathrm{TE}}_q &= \Re \frac{j\abs{E_0}^2}{2\eta} \notag\\
&\quad\times \oiint\limits_S \Bigl(
     A^i_qA^{i*}_q\bar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(1)*}_q 
   + A^i_qA^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(4)*}_q \notag\\
&\qquad
   + A^s_qA^{i*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(1)*}_q 
   + A^s_qA^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(4)*}_q \Bigr) \notag\\
&\qquad \cdot \hat{r}\mkern3mu ds \\[1ex]
P^{\mathrm{TM}}_q &= \Re\frac{j\abs{E_0}^2}{2\eta} \notag\\
&\quad\times \oiint\limits_S \Bigl(
    B^i_qB^{i*}_q\bar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(1)*}_q 
  + B^i_qB^{s*}_q\bar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(4)*}_q \notag\\
&\qquad
  + B^s_qB^{i*}_q\bar{N}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(1)*}_q 
  + B^s_qB^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(4)*}_q\Bigr) \notag\\
&\qquad\cdot \hat{r}\mkern3mu ds
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\endgroup
\hrule % just to illustrate width of column
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you happened to be pressed for space in your document, it's actually possible to typeset each equation in 3 rows instead of the 4 used both in your initial screenshot and in the answer above.

The following solution also uses `\widebar` (a macro provided by the `mathabx` package) instead of `\bar` as in the answer above. Using `\widebar` provides a "look" that replicates more closely the look of the screenshot you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article} % no 'fleqn' option
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathabx,esint}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\let\Re\relax 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re} % redefine '\Re'

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{24} % just for this example

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
&P^{\mathrm{TE}}_q = \Re \frac{j\abs{E_0}^2}{2\eta} 
\times \oiint\limits_{S} \Bigl\{
     A^i_qA^{i*}_q\widebar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \widebar{N}^{(1)*}_q \notag\\ 
&\quad+ A^i_qA^{s*}_q\widebar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \widebar{N}^{(4)*}_q 
   + A^s_qA^{i*}_q\widebar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \widebar{N}^{(1)*}_q  \notag\\
&\qquad+ A^s_qA^{s*}_q\widebar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \widebar{N}^{(4)*}_q \Bigr\}  \hat{r}\, ds \\[1ex]
&P^{\mathrm{TM}}_q = \Re\frac{j\abs{E_0}^2}{2\eta} 
\times \oiint\limits_{S} \Bigl\{
    B^i_qB^{i*}_q\widebar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \widebar{M}^{(1)*}_q \notag \\
&\quad+ B^i_qB^{s*}_q\widebar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \widebar{M}^{(4)*}_q 
  + B^s_qB^{i*}_q\widebar{N}^{(4)}_q \times \widebar{M}^{(1)*}_q \notag\\
&\qquad+ B^s_qB^{s*}_q\widebar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \widebar{M}^{(4)*}_q\Bigr\}  \hat{r}\, ds
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A different proposal, with more lines but shorter; typesetting math in two column format is always a pain.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{esint}

\let\Re\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
P^{TE}_q ={}& \Re\frac{j|E_0|^2}{2\eta} \\
{} \times \mathop{\smash[b]{\oiint\limits_S}}\Bigl(
  &  A^i_qA^{i*}_q\bar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(1)*}_q \\
  &+ A^i_qA^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(4)*}_q \\
  &+ A^s_qA^{i*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(1)*}_q \\
  &+ A^s_qA^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{N}^{(4)*}_q \Bigr) \cdot \hat{r}\,ds
  \end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
P^{TM}_q ={}& \Re\frac{j|E_0|^2}{2\eta} \\
{} \times \mathop{\smash[b]{\oiint\limits_S}}\Bigl(
 & B^i_qB^{i*}_q\bar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(1)*}_q \\
 &+ B^i_qB^{s*}_q\bar{N}^{(1)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(4)*}_q \\
 &+ B^s_qB^{i*}_q\bar{N}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(1)*}_q \\
 &+ B^s_qB^{s*}_q\bar{M}^{(4)}_q \times \bar{M}^{(4)*}_q \Bigr) \cdot \hat{r}\,ds
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\smash[b]` construction is to avoid the big integral pushes the line below it too much down. Wrapping it in `\mathop` ensures correct horizontal spacing.